# Jtable (getselectedrow) me devuelve -1

Tags: java, jtable

Hola estoy cargando un jtable con unos datos que tengo almacenados en una base de datos MySql, luego con un evento de mouseclicked selecciono un registro para editarlo y en dicha interfaz hay un boton que me muestra un jdialog para poder editar algunos registros de mi base de datos, el problema es que después de haber editado un registro o incluso si cierro el jdialog sin editar nada y quiero seleccionar otro registro, cualquier registro que seleccione me devuelve la posición -1.

El método para invocar al jdialog es el siguiente (aunque no creo que sea el problema):

```
private void btnActualizaUbicacionMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
    String rol = config.validacion();
    if (rol.equals("0")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No tiene el permiso para editar la ubicación", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        ActualzarUbicacionDialog dialogUbic = new ActualzarUbicacionDialog(this, true);
        ActualzarUbicacionDialog.lblProd.setText(txtNombreProd.getText());
        dialogUbic.setVisible(true);
        if (dialogUbic != null) {
            if (!dialogUbic.getInfo().equals(" ")) {
                updateTabla();
                txtUbicacion.setText(dialogUbic.getUbic());
            } else {
                updateTabla();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro. Pero creo que lo que quieres es poder modificar datos del JTable y que este a la vez modifique los datos almacenados en la base de datos.?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando selecciono un registro de mi jtable, este me devuelve -1.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que en el momento que se genera el evento en el JTable no tienes alguna fila o columna seleccionada y por ello te da el error. Tambien revisa que la tabla este instanciada con

> new

getSelectedColumn()
Returns the index of the first selected column, -1 if no column is selected.
getSelectedRow()
Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.